# Only receiving the column titles when using csvsimple and \csvautotabular

Tags: tables, csv, csvsimple

I'm currently running into an issue where I'll only get the titles of my columns showing for my table when using `csvsimple` with `\csvautotabular`.
[image: table problem]

The current code I used to produce this is

```
    \documentclass{report}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{csvsimple}
    
    \begin{document}
    \csvautotabular[respect all]{test_utf8.csv}
    \end{document}
```

I have used the test.csv

```
    Name,Battery %,Last updated
    L1 A / B (C),5%,"Sept. 1, 2021, 00:00 a.m."
    G D,12%,"Aug. 31, 2021, 9:09 a.m."
    L2 E / F (G),80%,"Feb. 21, 2021, 10:00 a.m."
```

which I believe has the general formatting required for my other csv files.

Answer (score 0):

Two changes solve the problem:

1. Changing `\csvautotabular[respect all]{test_utf8.csv}` to `\csvautotabular[respect percent]{test_utf8.csv}` (and other special characters that should be interpreted as normal characters).
2. Hiding commas which are not separators:

   ```
   Name,Battery %,Last updated
   L1 A  B (C),5%,{Sept. 1, 2021, 0000 a.m.}
   G D,12%,{Aug. 31, 2021, 909 a.m.}
   L2 E  F (G),80%,{Feb. 21, 2021, 1000 a.m.}
   ```

Because you need curly braces to mask a block that may contain
commas not to be processed as separators, you shouldn't choose `respect all`.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. 

So besides the change of use for the respect function, it's just a formatting issue in the csv itself? 

Currently I'm pasting data into excel and removing what columns/rows I don't need and saving as .csv. There's probably a quick way to replace the quotation marks with curly braces before I save to import into TeX.

Comment: @JacksonWright Yes, commas were used in two functions. If you are expecting many commas in your data, you can choose another separator in CSV files by, say, `[separator=semicolon]` as an option to `\csvautobooktabular`.

Comment: @JacksonWright I have just corrected the wrong `percent sings` in my answer. They certainly should be `commas`.

Comment: Cheers, the hardest part now is just getting a program to save it with curly brackets instead of quote marks hahaha :)

Comment: @JacksonWright Or omitting quote marks with `;` as a separator.

Comment: Yeah! Just anything that saves me having to do more by hand. Any way I can quickly get the site data into a .csv form that's good for TeX is gonna be perfect. I haven't really done much with .csv up until now. A bit more familiar with TeX generally from old thesis work etc.

Answer (score 0):

I thought I would take this space to show off the recently added (v3.0 2021-08-08) capability of the `readarray` package to create `tabular`s.  Because the file contains raw `%` tokens and uses quote grouping `"..."`, I required a little more setup to digest it.

Basically, the `\readdef` macro places the contents of a file into a `\def`, while the `\readarray` macro places the contents of the `\def` into an array.

The `\typesetarray` macro is newly introduced, and uses helper macros named `\typesetrowsepchar`, `\typesetcolsepchar` (also `\typesetplanesepchar` for 3-D) to format the typeset, as they are inserted between rows, columns, and/or planes.

EDITED to place the catcode stuff in its own macro, easing the burden on invocation setup.  Thus, the `\readdef` invocation is replaced with `\readdefquotespercents` in order to automatically digest raw `%` tokens as characters and to use quote-grouping.

RE-EDITED to use `\lowercase` magic to define the active character `"` inside of a macro.

```
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{junk.dat}
Name,Battery %,Last updated
L1 A / B (C),5%,"Sept. 1, 2021, 00:00 a.m."
G D,12%,"Aug. 31, 2021, 9:09 a.m."
L2 E / F (G),80%,"Feb. 21, 2021, 10:00 a.m."
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{readarray}[2021-08-08]
\readarraysepchar{,}
\renewcommand\typesetrowsepchar{\\\hline}
\renewcommand\typesetcolsepchar{&}

\newcommand\readdefquotespercents[2]{%
  \catcode`\"=\active
  \begingroup\lccode`\~=`"
  \lowercase{\endgroup\def~##1~}{{##1}}%
  \catcode`\%=12 \readdef{#1}#2\catcode`\%=14 
  \catcode`\"=12 
  \edef\tabdata{\tabdata}% CONVERT QUOTED PHRASES
}
\begin{document}
\readdefquotespercents{junk.dat}\tabdata

\readarray\tabdata\tabarray[-,\ncols]% PLACE def INTO ARRAY

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
\typesetarray\tabarray\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The length is too short to post the full error details but I'm getting the following errors with your code on Overleaf.

LaTeX Error: Command \typesetrowsepchar undefined.
LaTeX Error: Command \typesetcolsepchar undefined.
Undefined control sequence.
! Use of \tabarray doesn't match its definition.
l.28 \typesetarray\tabarray\\

Comment: @JacksonWright The readarray package seems outdated.  The one needed was released a month ago, [2021-08-08], v3.0

Comment: @JacksonWright see https://ctan.org/pkg/readarray